# How to Add filled circle in doghnut chart using chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to add a background color or a cirle with color inside doghnut chart using chartjs.
I have already added text in the center of doghnut chart.
However I am not able to add the background colour.
I also want to remove padding and margin chart.js inserts in the chart

I want a chart like this

[image: I want a chart like this]

I am able to acheive following using below code

[image: I am able to acheive following using below code]

This my code to render chart

```
                    data = {
                        labels: [
                            'performance'
                        ],
                        datasets: [{
                            label: 'performance;,
                            data: [90, 10],
                            backgroundColor: [
                                '#27AE60',
                                '#3333331A'
                            ]
                        }]
                    };
                    
                    config = {
                        type: 'doughnut',
                        data,
                        options: {
                            cutout: 200,
                            legend: {
                                display: false,
                            },
                            plugins: {
                                legend: {
                                    display: false
                                }
                            },
                            responsive: true,
                            rotation: 210, // start angle in degrees
                            circumference: 300,
                            radius: "50%"
                        },
                        plugins: [{
                            id: 'text',
                            beforeDraw: function (chart, a, b) {
                                let width = chart.width,
                                    height = chart.height,
                                    ctx = chart.ctx;

                                ctx.restore();
                                let fontSize = (height / 200).toFixed(2);
                                ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
                                ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

                                let text = '90%',
                                    textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
                                    textY = height / 2;

                                ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
                                ctx.save();
                            }
                        }],
                        centerText: {
                            display: true,
                            text: "280"
                        }
                    };
               
                    new Chart('performance', config);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mimic this design by using a pie chart with specific configuration options.

Here is a working example, including the posted plugin code for drawing text in the middle (note that the plugin is changed from `beforeDraw` to `afterDraw` to keep the text above the fill segment):

```js
const data = {
  datasets: [{
    label: 'outer',
    data: [1, 2],
    backgroundColor: [
      '#27AE60',
      '#3333331A'
    ],
    rotation: 210,
    circumference: 300,
    cutout: '50%',
    borderWidth: 0
  }, {
    // dummy dataset to fill middle.
    label: 'inner',
    data: [1],
    backgroundColor: '#27AE60',
    weight: 3,
    borderWidth: 0
  }]
};

new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'pie',
  data: data,
  options: {
    borderAlign: 'inner'
  },
  plugins: [{
    id: 'text',
    afterDraw: function(chart, a, b) {
      let width = chart.width,
        height = chart.height,
        ctx = chart.ctx;

      ctx.restore();
      let fontSize = (height / 200).toFixed(2);
      ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
      ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

      let text = '90%',
        textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
        textY = height / 2;

      ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
      ctx.save();
    }
  }],
});
```

```html
<div style="width:200px;height:200px"><canvas id="chart"></canvas></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.2.1"></script>
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked thank you so much, but in my case, the green circle overrides "90%"  text, what should i do ?

Comment: I should have noted that in the answer - change the plugin from `beforeDraw` to `afterDraw`.